# Parsing a string in SQL with If statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I have a table with a string in some columns values that tells me if I should delete the row....however this string needs some parsing to understand whether to delete or not.

What is the string: it tells me the recurrence of meetings eg everyday starting 21st march for 10 meetings.

My table is a single column called `recurrence`:

```
Recurrence
-------------------------------
daily;1;21/03/2015;times;10
daily;1;01/02/2016;times;8
monthly;1;01/01/2016;times;2
weekly;1;21/01/2016;times;4
```

What to do: if the meetings are finished then remove the row.

The string is of the following format

```
<frequency tag>;<frequency number>;<start date>;times;<no of times>
```

For example

```
daily;1;21/03/2016;times;10
```

everyday  starting 21st march, for 10 times

Does anybody know how I would calculate if the string indicates all meetings are in past? I want a select statement that tells me if the recurrence values are in past - true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added one string `('weekly;1;21/05/2016;times;4')` that definitely must not be deleted to show some output. At first try to add to temp table `@table1' all data from your table and check if all is deleted well.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (
    Recurrence nvarchar(max)
)
DECLARE @xml xml

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
('daily;1;21/03/2016;times;10'),
('daily;1;21/03/2015;times;10'),
('daily;1;01/02/2016;times;8'),
('monthly;1;01/01/2016;times;2'),
('weekly;1;21/01/2016;times;4'),
('weekly;1;21/05/2016;times;4')


SELECT @xml= (
SELECT CAST('<s><r>' + REPLACE(Recurrence,';','</r><r>') + '</r><r>'+ Recurrence+'</r></s>' as xml)
FROM @table1
FOR XML PATH ('')
)

;WITH cte as (
SELECT  t.v.value('r[1]','nvarchar(10)') as how,
        t.v.value('r[2]','nvarchar(10)') as every,
        CONVERT(date,t.v.value('r[3]','nvarchar(10)'),103) as since,
        t.v.value('r[4]','nvarchar(10)') as what,
        t.v.value('r[5]','int') as howmany,
        t.v.value('r[6]','nvarchar(max)') as Recurrence
FROM @xml.nodes('/s') as t(v)
)

DELETE t
FROM @table1 t
LEFT JOIN cte c ON c.Recurrence=t.Recurrence
WHERE 
     CASE WHEN how = 'daily' THEN DATEADD(day,howmany,since)
            WHEN how = 'weekly' THEN DATEADD(week,howmany,since)
            WHEN how = 'monthly' THEN DATEADD(month,howmany,since)
            ELSE NULL END < GETDATE()

SELECT * FROM @table1
```

Output:

```
Recurrence
-----------------------------
weekly;1;21/05/2016;times;4

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thx gofr1. How can i take this and complete my requirement of deciding whether to delete a row or not? (delete if all recurrence in past)

Comment: @Fearghal then provide more samples of data, add some guidance may that strings pass or not. Also you show only daily variant, is there any other?

Comment: For example CASE WHEN how = 'daily' THEN dateadd(day,howmany,since) WHEN how=... END there will be dates that you can compare with current date.

Comment: ok thx @gofr1, i'll try ot suss it out given your last comment and get back to you. At present i have daily, weekly and monthly.

Comment: apologies gofr1 - i see you included my description in the example vsytring to be parsed. This description is not part of the value but when i remove it to be left with daily;1;21/03/2016;times;10 it breaks the code. Can you amend your code to only use daily;1;;21/03/2016;times;10?

Comment: @Fearghal that's why more data samples are required! It's difficult to make some good code without nice, big samples with various cases of data.

Comment: I just added some, is that ok? It has weekly, monthly, daily etc?

Comment: It's ok. But you said something about string with ';;'

Comment: apologies, typo on the double ';'

Comment: Is there any ID's on your table?

Comment: fantastic, that works abs amazing. I just need to point it to an actual table instead of having the values hardcoded and it should do the trick. thx so much! Superstar.